# "Requested entity was not found." - Apps Script Execution API error

Tags: java, google-api-java-client, google-apps-script-api

We have an Apps Script that is installed in five G Suite accounts. I am invoking the app scripts from the Java code that is being deployed in Google App Engine. I have stored the five refresh tokens in a properties file and set them in GoogleCredential in a round robin fashion before invoking the Apps Script. When I am trying to invoke the Apps Script `Requested entity was not found.`, an error is returned. But the same refresh tokens and client secrets work fine when I create a simple java program to invoke the Apps Script.

```
@Service
public class GoogleAppsScriptServiceImpl {
    private String[] scriptIds;

    private String[] refreshTokens;

    private GoogleCerdential credential;

    public void executeAppsScript() {
        List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(googleDocFileId);

        ExecutionRequest request = new ExecutionRequest()
                                        .setFunction(APPS_SCRIPT_FUNCTION_NAME)
                                        .setParameters(params);

        int index = new Random().nextInt(numOfUsers);

        Script scriptService = getScriptService(refreshTokens[index]);
        String scriptId = scriptIds[index];

        Operation operation = scriptService.scripts()
                            .run(scriptId, request)
                            .setQuotaUser(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                            .execute();
    }

    private Script getScriptService(String refreshToken) {
        credential.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        return new Script.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                         .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                         .build();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void createGoogleCredential() throws Exception {
        jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                                    .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                                    .build();

        refreshTokens = commaDelimitedListToStringArray(refreshTokensProp);
        numOfUsers = refreshTokens.length;

        scriptIds = commaDelimitedListToStringArray(scriptsIdsProp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not with the configuration of Apps Script or the App Engine project. I was creating a `GoogleCredential` object in the `@PostConstruct` method and set the refresh tokens (`credential.setRefreshToken()`) from the list of pre-generated tokens before invoking the Apps Script. Even though I had created the refresh tokens for the same set of Client ID and Client Secret, I was getting the error. So, I am creating multiple `GoogleCredential` objects as the number of refresh tokens and not re-use the credentials object across multiple refresh tokens.

```
private GoogleCredential[] credentials;

@PostConstruct
private void createGoogleCredential() throws Exception {
    jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    String[] refreshTokens = commaDelimitedListToStringArray(refreshTokensProp);
    numOfUsers = refreshTokens.length;

    credentials = new GoogleCredential[numOfUsers];
    for (int i=0; i<numOfUsers; i++) {
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                        .setTransport(httpTransport)
                                        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                                        .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
                                        .build();

        credential.setRefreshToken(refreshTokens[i]);

        credentials[i] = credential;
    }

    scriptIds = commaDelimitedListToStringArray(scriptsIdsProp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are deploying Execution API to a project of the standalone script type or the container-bound script type. And you call the function in the project using the API. Under the situation, the error of `Requested entity was not found.` occurs. If my understanding is correct, I had also experienced the same situation. So how about confirming the following points?

1. Using the save button, save the project which is deploying API executable again.

   - This was very important for me.
2. Save the project as a new version, and redeploy the API.
3. Whether the client ID and client secret are retrieved from the project that Apps Script API is used.

   - Whether the access token is retrieved from these client ID and client secret.
4. Whether the scope includes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`.
5. Whether Execution API is enabled.

If you want to simply test using curl command, you can also use the following command.

```
curl -X POST -L \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{function: '### function name ###',devMode: true}" \
    "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

After confirmed above points, please try again. If these were not useful for you, I'm sorry. Or if I misunderstand your question, I'm really sorry.